# I'm trying to write a simple whatsapp bot with selenium but the messaging loop won't work properly. What is the problem?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

```
    textbar = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p')
    while(True):
        message = input("Please enter the text you want to  send to the selected person to stop the program type -exit- : ")    
        textbar.send_keys(message)
        if(message == "exit"):
            break
        textbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: what does "won't work properly" mean?

Comment: please post the error message if any

Comment: The loop stops after 2 strings and it won't send the first string that is typed.

Comment: Here is the error message: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're calling `textbar.send_keys(message)` before checking if the message is `exit`. You should move up your `if` statement so that you exit the program sooner. And put the `find_element` inside the loop to avoid `StaleElementReferenceException`. Eg:

```py
while(True):
    message = input("Please enter the text you want to send to the selected person. To stop the program, type -exit- : ")
    if(message == "exit"):
        break
    textbar = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p')
    textbar.send_keys(message)
    textbar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still get errors-->
Selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: I updated it just now. Put the `find_element` call inside the loop to avoid the `StaleElementReferenceException`. And you probably want a more reliable selector for the textbar.